# xacro processing in ROS 2 YAML launch files (or XML)?

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, yaml, xacro, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use YAML launch files for a Gazebo simulation project I'm working on, but it doesn't seem like there's a lot of documentation beyond the basics [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Launch-file-different-formats.html).

I need to process a robot description `xacro` and pass that as a `param` to `robot_state_publisher`.

Does the YAML frontend support this?

Does someone know of an example in an existing package?

I should be able to RUN the `xacro` processing with an `executable` but it's not clear how I'd store and access the variable. (I could probably put it into an env var and then read the env var, but that seems like a roundabout way to

https://design.ros2.org/articles/roslaunch_xml.html#executable-tag

Here I'm linking to XML docs because there's not much on YAML that I can find, but it seems from other recent investigations like YAML and XML are almost exactly the same.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413817/xacro-processing-in-ros-2-yaml-launch-files-(or-xml)?/) by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 337 on 2023-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer here https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/366#issuecomment-572750757

There is a `$(command ...)` substitution that can be processed into a value, like:

```
- let:
    name: "robot_description_content"
    value: "$(command '$(find-exec xacro) $(var robot_xacro) name:=ur ur_type:=ur5e')"
```

Ultimately the same as `launch.substitutions.Command()` in a Python launch file.

---

Originally posted by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) with karma: 337 on 2023-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In an `xml` launch file I was able to process my `xacro` via

```
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" exec="robot_state_publisher"
        <param name='robot_description' type="str" value="$(command 'xacro $(find-pkg-share myrobot_description)/urdf/robot.urdf.xacro')"/>
</node>
```

Note that I added the following line to the `data_files` member in `setup.py`

```
(os.path.join('share', package_name, 'urdf'), glob(os.path.join('urdf', '*[urdf][xacro]*')))
```

This was a slightly different approach than stated in the [urdf tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Intermediate/URDF/Using-URDF-with-Robot-State-Publisher.html#edit-the-setup-py-file) and allowed my description files to be copied to the shared directory within a urdf folder.

---

Originally posted by [chives_onion](https://answers.ros.org/users/39292/chives_onion/) with karma: 180 on 2023-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1