# How to pass to URDF to robot_state_publisher in YAML launch file?

Tags: ros2, urdf, xacro, yaml, launch-file

I am writing a simple YAML launch file to launch my URDF. With robot_state_publisher publishing the robot description to rviz2. But how do i pass the output of `xacro <file>` to the node?

In python launch file I achieved this using:

```py
start_robot_state_publisher = Node(name="robot_state_publisher",
                                       executable="robot_state_publisher",
                                       package="robot_state_publisher",
                                       parameters = [{"robot_state_description": Command(['xacro ', LaunchConfiguration('urdf_model')])}],
                                       arguments=[urdf_loc]
                                        );
```

Comment: See here for YAML: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/103145/33390 The other answer there covers XML